# Latest Vaadin Start generated app - bug in main-layout theme with Flow/Hybrid views?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin21

I used the latest Vaadin Start page to generate an app skeleton (Vaadin 21 / Java 11)
It works so far, I used hybrid mode with various views.

When clicking view links in the menu only TS+HTML based views will register in the GUI as selected and get a colored "selected/active" styling.

When I generate an app which only has Flow views, the first view will be stuck with the selected styling, but other views will register properly when clicked.

Only when I generate an app which only has Fusion views, all view selects will properly register.

I guess this is a bug?

Edit: video of the behavior when in hybrid mode. The menu item names correspond to the type of view which is being selected. As you can see only fusion views show the "select" in the menu:

[image: video of the behavior]

Edit2: I think the problem is caused here:

```
?highlight=${viewRoute.path == appStore.location
```

Seems like the appStore.location is not being set from non-Fusion views. I put a console.log in the index.ts eventListener and non-Fusion views all just pass "(.*)" as the view name/location, which is the reasion why this fails.

So the @Route(value = "view-name") declaration in the java-class seems not to be passed properly at the moment.

BR
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the Start project templates. I added an issue in our internal issue tracker.

Thanks a lot for reporting.

Edit: the issue is already fixed.

Comment: Thank you!

Is the fix documented somewhere (publicly)?

If it's trivial I could fix it manually in my project.

Comment: I think I have noticed even more bugs, the title of the view (e.g. Hello World view example) is also not being set in non-Fusion views.

Comment: The repository is private, but the fix looks pretty trivial: in app-store.ts (in `frontend/stores/`) the `if (location.route)` check has changed into a `if (location.route && location.route.path != '(.*)')` check. Or you could download a new version and copy your code over.

Comment: Hi, I've already checked the app-store.ts and it seems like the location.route.title is not being passed respectively undefined in the case of non-Fusion views.

So the current code there sets it as an empty string: 
this.currentViewTitle = (location?.route as any)?.title || '';

Comment: Ok, I've now found the root cause of this.

When generating an app stub with the Vaadin Start tool the ViewRoute elements for JAVA and JAVA+HTML views are not added to the routes.ts

Adding them manually fixes the problem with location.route.title being undefined in the app-store.ts

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear to me, but if the problem is the fact that "the first view will be stuck with the selected styling", have you tried to add setAutoselect(false) to the tabbed menu in your MainLayout?

Here it is:

```
private Tabs createMenu() {
    final Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
    tabs.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.VERTICAL);
    tabs.addThemeVariants(TabsVariant.LUMO_MINIMAL);
    tabs.setId("tabs");
    tabs.setAutoselect(false); //Needed not to select first tab by default
    tabs.add(createMenuItems());
    return tabs;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

my generated stub uses the hybrid view which uses the main-layout.ts and gets the menuitems from the route list through the getMenuRoutes() (where they are listed) to generate the <nav> element.

I'm posting here because this is the "out-of-the-box" behavior of the generated app stub if you generate a starter application using hybrid mode.

I'm guessing this is a bug and I only noticed this since I tried the starter tool with Vaadin 21 and this didn't seem to occur with the Vaadin 20-based generated starter application a few weeks ago.

BR.

Comment: I have added a video/gif of the behavior to the original post.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with Fusion. If all views are java-based, the "tabs.setAutoselect(false);" should solve the issue. But for ts+java views the route manager is client-side, so you should check where the "selected" is set with Fusion.